# On the operation that transforms a set into a set of sets of individual elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, terminology

In the context of a math-oriented computing library, I am wondering how to name the operation that consists of transforming a set of objects into a set of sets of individual objects:

$\{A, B, C\} \Rightarrow \{\{A\}, \{B\}, \{C\}\}$

How can this be viewed from a set-theoretic perspective, and how could I name this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest calling the operation $\mathsf{singletons}(X)$.

A singleton set is a set containing precisely one element, such as $\{a\}$. Your operation results in a collection of all the elements of the set $X$, individually wrapped in a set:
$$\mathsf{singletons}(X) = \{  \{x\} : x\in X\}$$

You can also view this operation as forming the set of all one-element subsets of $X$:

$$\mathsf{singletons}(X) = \{A\subseteq X : |A|=1\}$$

Both views are equivalent, and in my view the name does a reasonable job of communicating what the operator does.

---

Aside:
If you wanted to instead define this operator in terms of more primitive, general functions, you might use $\mathsf{wrap}(a) \equiv \{a\}$ and $\mathsf{map}(f,X) \equiv \{f(x) : x\in X\}$, in which case $\mathsf{singletons}(X) = \mathsf{map}(\mathsf{wrap}, X).$